# Spark - Choosing the right number of partitions

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce

I'm using `GroupByTest` example App as a benchmark for testing my shuffle manager implementation.

The problem with using `GroupByTest` for someone who is not experienced with using Spark on real datasets is that `GroupByTest` is very flexible.

You need to choose the size of the data (numMappers * numKVPairs * valSize), how the data is split (numMappers), and the number of reducers that affects the size of the shuffle blocks.

My shuffle manager is doing very good job exchanging "big" reduce partitions. I lack certainty about the term "big" due to my limited experience working with Spark on actual datasets.

What I'm trying to understand is what is typical reduce partition size?
What is the rule of thumb for choosing the right number of partitions? I know that it depends on the cluster capabilities.

Comment: I'd say there is no such thing as the right number of partitions (or partition size). It is all highly dependent on use-case and type of processing carried out. Commonly, people shoot for anywhere between 40 - 200 MB per partition but that may vary.